# What can I say about the consecutive difference of a convergent sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose sequence $x_r\to 0$. Then what can I say about sequence $x_{r+1}-x_r$?does it converge to zero?

Comment: $x^{r+1}-x^r = x^r(x-1) \xrightarrow{} 0 \cdot (x-1) = 0$

Comment: Do you intend the superscript $r$ to be a power or have you perversely intended it as an index for your sequence (which is widely indicated with subscripts)?

Comment: That was the index of the sequence. Edited.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that $x_{r}\rightarrow0$ is irrelevant, so let's proceed
assuming $x_{r}\rightarrow x$ (i.e., the sequence converges).

Then,
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\left\{ x_{r}-x_{r+1}\right\} =\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}x_{r}-\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}x_{r+1}=x-x=0.
$$
In the above, we used the fact that $x_{r+1}\rightarrow x$ and that the limit
of sums is the sum of limits.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Convergent sequences are Cauchy, thus...

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon>0$

$$x_r\to x \implies \exists N\ge 0 \; : $$
$$\; \forall r\ge N \;\; |x_r-x|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

but for $r\ge N$, we have

$$r+1>r\ge N$$ thus
for $r\ge N,$

$$|x_{r+1}-x_r|\le |x_{r+1}-x|+|x_r-x|<\epsilon$$

done.